# Replace non-image elements in DOM tree with text in JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, contenteditable

I would like to replace non-`img` elements inside a `contenteditable` with their text. However, I want to preserve any `img` elements, including those nested inside other elements. In other words:

Given input such as:

```
<div><span>Foo <strong>Bar <img src="blah.png"></strong> and more text <img src="another.png"></span> With some other text <img src="yetmore.png"></div>
```

I would like to produce:

```
Foo Bar <img src="blah.png"> and more text <img src="another.png"> With some other text <img src="yetmore.png">
```

As this is a `contenteditable`, I don't want to use `innerHTML` reading/writing, as that will lose cursor position and the like (restoring it is Hard, because you end up with a different DOM tree so your selection nodes get lost).

Is my best bet to just iterate over the tree and manually split and concatenate text nodes and so on? I'm hoping there's a better way, or a library that can already do things like this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a shallow clone of the root element. Walk down the original's element tree, collecting text. When you come across an img element, add the text gathered so far as a text node that is a child of the clone. Append the img. Start collecting text again.

Keep going until you get to the end, then replace the original root element in the document with the clone.

#### Edit

Something like:

```
function toArray(o) {
  var a = [], i = o.length;
  while (i--) {
    a[i] = o[i];
  }
  return a;
}

function cleanUp(el) {

  var e = el.cloneNode(false);

  function addText(text) {
    if (text != '') {
      e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    }
  }

  function collectText(el) {
    var node, nodes = toArray(el.childNodes);
    var text = '';

    for (var i=0, iLen=nodes.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      node = nodes[i];

      if (node.tagName && node.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'img') {
        addText(text);
        e.appendChild(node);
        text = '';

      } else if (node.nodeType == 3) {
        text += node.data;

      } else if (node.nodeType == 1) {
        addText(text);
        text = '';
        collectText(node);
      }
    }

    if (text != '') {
      e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    }
  }
  collectText(el);
  el.parentNode.replaceChild(e, el);
}
```

Comment: I ended up using this solution - thanks! I did still have to fiddle with it a little bit, and made it concatenate subsequent text into one text node, even if it spanned nested elements. Then I had to still deal with the focus/cursor position. Fortunately, in my case I only really need to do this kind of cleanup on paste, in which case the focus should always be after the last node of replaced content, which is pretty easy to do programmatically.

Comment: Oh, and I ended up creating an array of nodes to insert, and then called insertBefore, and finally removeChild on `el`, rather than the cloneNode... this way I can discriminately use it against offending `childNodes` of my contenteditable, which speeds up my code and avoids doing the costly treewalking for ordinary typing (where the same function is being run).

Answer (score 3):

Doing DOM replacement will almost certainly lose the cursor position / selection as well, but is still the correct approach. I'd recommend [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy) for [saving and restoring the selection](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/SelectionSaveRestoreModule), and cross-browser Range/selection handling (disclosure: I am Rangy's author).

Here's an example that removes non-`<img>` elements and retains the previous selection/caret position in all major browsers (including IE 6). It recursively moves the `<img>` and text descendants of the main container node into a `DocumentFragment` and removes all other nodes as it goes along before finally appending the fragment into the now-empty container node. It also normalizes (i.e. concatenates adjacent text nodes).

jsFiddle with Rangy selection save and restore: http://jsfiddle.net/CRLRj/1/

Element removal code:

```
function removeNonImgElements(node) {
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

    function move(node, moveSelf) {
        var type = node.nodeType, name = node.nodeName;

        // Deal with child nodes first
        var child;
        while ( (child = node.firstChild) ) {
            move(child, true);
        }

        if (!moveSelf) {
            return;
        }

        // Keep text, images and Rangy selection marker elements
        if (type == 1 && (name == "IMG" ||
                 (name == "SPAN" && /^selectionBoundary/.test(node.id)))) {
            frag.appendChild(node);
        } else if (type == 3) {
            var previousNode = frag.lastChild;
            if (previousNode && previousNode.nodeType == 3) {
                // Concatenate text nodes rather than have two adjacent
                previousNode.data = previousNode.data + node.data;
                node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
            } else {
                frag.appendChild(node);
            }
        } else {
            node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
        }
    }

    move(node, false);
    node.appendChild(frag);
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't bother with the *hasChildNodes* test, since you are removing nodes you could just keep going while there is a *firstChild*. Good idea to concatenate adjacent text nodes.

Comment: @RobG: Yes, I agree with you. I'm not sure why I put that in; I wouldn't normally bother. I'll remove it.

Comment: I +'d this, but ended up going with Rob's solution, because adding Rangy is a bit too heavy-handed for what I'm doing (admittedly, if I keep saying that and end up with thousands of lines of code to hack around issues, I should probably re-evaluate - but we're not at that point yet.

In our app, we're sanitizing on paste / keydown / mouseup / mousedown. That means focus should always be after the last node of the replaced content, which I did by just hardcoding a range with `setStartAfter` to `window.getSelection` after such a cleanup. This seems to work well in my testing.

Comment: @Gijs: Fair enough. The main use case for Rangy is if you're supporting IE < 9, which I assume you're not if you're using Ranges and `window.getSelection`. Having said that, the Rangy involvement in the function above is minimal and easily removed, but @RobG's solution is just as good.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    replaceChildren($('#contenteditable'));
});

function replaceChildren(elem){
    $(elem).children("*").not("img").each(function(){
        if ($(this).children("*").not("img").length>0){
            replaceChildren(this);
        }
        $(this).after($(this).html());
        $(this).remove();
    });
}
```

Some kind of recursive solution.

Comment: That still uses `innerHTML` in the `after()` call.